# How do I change the default location Blender opens when I want to install an add-on from file?

Tags: interface, add-on

In case a picture can help to clarify, I am specifically hoping to find a way to alter this location, which seems to default (on Windows) to the current user's Documents/ subfolder:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "The default location Blender opens in"?

Comment: I mean that, when I select Edit > Preferences > Addon > Install, this appears to default to my user's Documents/ folder, although its behavior seems to change sometimes in ways I don't quite understand yet. I would like to be able to specify e.g. in an interface preference setting the folder that Edit > Preferences > Addon > Install opens.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I see. So to change this, you may want to go to the *File* tab in the USER PREFERENCES. To change the location Blender defaults to installing add-ons from, you need to change the location of the render cache. This can be done by clicking on the *Render Cache* file preferences in the file tab, and choosing a location in your computer or on an external drive. This should solve your problem.